# "Rectangles" and "cylinders". Why are they called like that?

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory, definition, intuition

First, let us consider:

> $$H=(H_1,\ldots,H_k)\in\mathbb{R}^k$$
> with $H_i\in\mathbb{R}^1,\text{ each } i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.
> $H$ is defined as a **"rectangle"**, but I cannot undertand why (consider what happens for $k>2$). Is it just a matter of convention or is there a geometrical reason behind that definition?

Secondly:

> Denote the collection of all maps from $T=\{0,1,2...\}$ into the real line $\mathbb{R}^1$ as $\mathbb{R}^T$. For each $t\in T$ define a mapping $Z_t:\mathbb{R}^T\mapsto \mathbb{R}^1$ by $$Z_t(x)=x(t)=x_t$$
> Now, consider sets of the form:
> $$\big[x\in\mathbb{R}^T:\left(Z_{t_1}(x),\ldots,Z_{t_{k}}(x)\right)\in H\big]$$
> with $H\in\mathbb{R}^k$ as before.
> Sets with this form are called **"finite-dimensional sets"** or **"cylinders"**. 
> The second question is in the same spirit of the first one regarding rectangles: why are they exactly called cylinders? Is there a geometrical reason behind that?

Comment: I think you are missing something in the definition of $H$, as it seems with the current wording, $H=\Bbb R^k$.

Comment: I cannot get what you mean. I wrote $H\in\mathbb{R}^k$

Comment: Do you mean $H_i \subset \mathbb R$ or $H_i \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @ArcticChar $H_i\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Um... where did you someone call this a rectangle? Please include that.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I have not properly understood the context, I don't know. Anyway, read it in Billingsley (1995), section 36, "Product Spaces" @ArcticChar

Comment: In the book they use $H  = H_1 \times \cdots \times H_k$ and $H_i \in \mathscr R^1$, which is different from $R^k$, or $R^1$, where they used to denote the euclidean space. I did not check what is $\mathscr R^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $H$ with $H_i\in \Bbb R$  defines a point. To define a rectangular set $H$ we usually require that $H_i\subset \Bbb R$. I think a rectangular intuition for this sets is based on an observation that a rectangle can be imagined as a Cartesian product of its projections.

I think the cylindrical intuition for the respective sets is based on their model as a cylinder with a finitely-dimensional rectangular base, Cartesianly multiplied by an infinitely-dimensional set.

Comment: Sorry for my very basic questions: I believed that a rectangle has just two projections, but for $k>2$ projections would be more than $2$ (hence, Cartesian product would involve more than $2$ projections). So, first, what is the definition of a projection of a rectangle? Could you please give me some reference? As to the cylinder part, could you please restate it in a plainer way so as to help me understand (even just visually) what you mean. Thank you a lot @AlexRavsky

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Projections of a rectangle are shown in red [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WACMm.png). A usual (two-dimensional) rectangle can be imagined as a Cartesian product of its two projections, but this can be naturally generalized to a high-dimensional case. At the same picture is also shown a cylinder $B\times\Bbb R_+$ in $\Bbb R^3_+$, with a base $B$ colored grey.

Comment: How could I imagine a rectangle in a three dimensional setting for example? Sorry, but I cannot imagine that. Additionally, why above do you say "a cylinder with a finitely-dimensional rectangular base"? I am used to think of cylinders as objects with a circular base (as in the picture you shared in your comment) @AlexRavsky

Comment: @Strictly_increasing  An example of a rectangle in a three dimensional setting is a cube. The cylindrical sets are generalized cylinderes, they can have a rectangular base.